# AVR-Toolchain for Arduino crashes on Mac OSX 10.11.6: Hints or debugging help needed

Tags: avr, mac-os, avr-toolchain, avr-gcc

My Arduino IDE does not compile any project since I updated from Mac OSX 10.6.8 to 10.11.6.

I even tried reinstalling and also manually installing the original AVR-toolchain. But the behaviour did not change.

I still get the following error messages

```
signal: bus error
Fehler beim Kompilieren für das Board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

English translation of the error message is:

```
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

- Is this problem known? I could not find information about it.
- Are there any known solutions to it?
- Can I start Arduino IDE in debug
  mode to give some usefull output what exactly causes the crash?

**EDIT**

I am using the current IDE 1.8.5 and also tried the nightly builds. I also tried some older versions down to 1.6.0.

**EDIT 2:**

Arduino 1.0.5 produces the following error:

```
cc1plus: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 3**

After installing UECIDE (what went smoothly) I am facing the same problem. The error happens in the AVR toolchain when calling the avr-gcc 4.9.2 compiler. In UECID the output tab shows the following output (I added linebreaks for readability):

```
~/Library/uecide/compilers/avr-gcc/bin/avr-g++ 
  -c /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-faf1be1e-2186-438b-9e1a-c56f50ce26d1/MySource.cpp 
  -o /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-faf1be1e-2186-438b-9e1a-c56f50ce26d1/MySource.cpp.o
  -mmcu=atmega328p -g -std=gnu++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics
  -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
  -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=106 -DARDUINO_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR
  -I~/Library/uecide/cores/arduino/arduino
  -I~/Library/uecide/boards/Arduino/arduino-uno
  -I/var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-faf1be1e-21
86-438b-9e1a-c56f50ce26d1
  -I~/pro/Arduino/MySource -Os -w
```

The status tab of UECID only shows `Compiling Failed`.

**EDIT 4**

After starting UECID from console with `--debug --verbose` options specified it did print the failing command to console:

```
~/Library/uecide/compilers/avr-gcc/bin/avr-g++ 
   -c /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-5ccb5f12-fcd1-4893-8c41-39fc056ec544/MySourve.cpp
   -o /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-5ccb5f12-fcd1-4893-8c41-39fc056ec544/MySourve.cpp.o
   -mmcu=atmega328p -g -std=gnu++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics
   -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
   -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=106 -DARDUINO_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR
   -I~/Library/uecide/cores/arduino/arduino
   -I~/Library/uecide/boards/Arduino/arduino-uno
   -I/var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-5ccb5f12-fcd1-4893-8c41-39fc056ec544
   -I~/pro/Arduino/MySourve -Os -w
```

This command is identical to the one created by Arduino.

I found another hint on a [bug in gcc 4.8 that seems not to be AVR specific](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2336).

After reducing the command line to

```
~/Library/uecide/compilers/avr-gcc/bin/avr-g++ 
  -c /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-5ccb5f12-fcd1-4893-8c41-39fc056ec544/MySource.cpp
  -o /var/folders/2h/8pdnzj197tq906bzs81ksn6m0000gn/T/build-5ccb5f12-fcd1-4893-8c41-39fc056ec544/MySource.cpp.o
```

the crash stays the same: `Segmentation fault 11`

Comment: Arduino IDE version? Maybe is time to try UECIDE (http://uecide.org)

Comment: I run 10.13.3 without any problem. Suggest to update the IDE. You can read also this article to use TextWrangler or BBEdit as editor with direct link to compile, assemble and so on. https://feroce-lapin.blogspot.com.br/2017/12/arduino-et-bbedit-textwrangler.html

Comment: I just tried the arduino web IDE. Strangely this crashes on uploading the sketch with avrdude. If I copy paste the command to a terminal window it runs and program is flashed to arduino board.

Comment: @Look Alterno: I am using the current IDE 1.8.5 and also tried the nightly builds. I also tried some older versions down to 1.6.0

Comment: There are a lot of older versions of the IDE on the Arduino web site. I don't think it particularly matters which one you use. Try using an earlier one.

Comment: When you try re-installing the IDE, make sure you clear out any old preferences that may be referencing any manually installed toolchain that may not be correct. Especially at /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: Do you happen to have any anti-virus software running which might be blocking the compiler?

Comment: I also thought about this possibility. I use Intego VirusBarrier. I deactivated the real time protection, no change.

Comment: What about your source? Does it have any multi-byte characters (Unicode)? Call any external libraries?

Comment: It seems to happen with any source. e.g "blink" example from arduino